# TypeError: jQuery(...).bindFirst is not a function

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am using a wordpress plugin, which was working fine but now it's giving
TypeError: jQuery(...).bindFirst is not a function.

can anyone help me for this.

I updated the plugins but still not working

```
ES.prototype = {
init : function(form){
    jQuery(form).bindFirst('submit', function(e) {
        window.es.addSubscriber(e, jQuery(e.target));
    }); // submit Event
},
```

Comment: Can you share the url, so I can try something in console and get exact error ?

Comment: Thanks @Harsh Khare, I have changed bindFirst to bind and now it's working.